# plugin operation launch every time i click on page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I created a plugin for specific heavy batch operation but it seems that every time I click on any other place (list posts , list page , ....) the heavy operation is launched again, so I want to know how i can launch the plugin operation only when I activate him like singleton.

bellow the code I use to avoid this kind of behavior but it doesn't work:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation' );
function my_plugin_activation() {
  add_option( 'my_plugin_activation','just-activated' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init','my_plugin_initialize' );
function my_plugin_initialize() {
    if( is_admin() && get_option( 'my_plugin_activation' ) == 'just-activated' ) {
    delete_option( 'my_plugin_activation' );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
```

Could you help .

Comment: What does your heavy operation do? Keep in mind that things you do on one page request have no effect on another, each page request is built from scratch. PHP isn't like Node or Python apps where a single program handles all requests, when you request a page in PHP everything is loaded in from scratch, nothing persists unless you store it in the database or filesystem. Have you considered a custom WP CLI command?

Comment: `admin_init` runs on every admin page. If you're wanting to only run the batch job when the plugin is activated, move the operation inside of your `my_plugin_activation()` function. If instead you're wanting it to run periodically, you could set up a cron job, or you could set it up only to run when a specific admin screen is visited.